# Java checkbox issue

Tags: java, checkbox, label, awt

I have some problem when using `checkbox` with group. I use event action to get `checkbox` label string. I'm using two groups for `checkbox` and when I click on the first `checkbox` at that time label's text will be changed. But when I click on the first group `checkbox`, both lables get changed.

Here is my code:

```
/* <applet code="third.class" width=500 height=500></applet> */

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class third extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
private  Label l1,l2;
private Checkbox cb,cbj2;
CheckboxGroup grp = new CheckboxGroup();
CheckboxGroup grp2 = new CheckboxGroup();
public void init()
{



    Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox("Mango",grp,false);
    Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox("Apple",grp,false);
    Checkbox cb3 = new Checkbox("Orange",grp,false);

    Checkbox cbj1 = new Checkbox("Male",grp2,false);
    Checkbox cbj2 = new Checkbox("Female",grp2,false);

    FlowLayout f1=new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    FlowLayout f2=new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
    FlowLayout f3=new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);

    cb1.addItemListener(this);
    cb2.addItemListener(this);
    cb3.addItemListener(this);

    cbj1.addItemListener(this);
    cbj2.addItemListener(this);

    setLayout(f3);
    add(cb1);
    add(cb2);
    add(cb3);

    l1 = new Label("                                                         ");
    add(l1);

    setLayout(f2);
    add(cbj1);
    add(cbj2);              

    l2 = new Label("                                                         ");
    add(l2);
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{

    cb=(Checkbox)(e.getItemSelectable());
    l1.setText(cb.getLabel());

    cb2=(Checkbox)(e.getItemSelectable());
    l2.setText(cb2.getLabel());
}   
}
```

View image here !!

http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/9779/76059549.png

The problem is that when I click on first `checkbox` group at that time both label strings get changed.
So how can I stop that ?

Comment: there are compile errors in your code (variable `cb2` in method `itemStateChanged` not defined), please fix those.
Also I think that the problem has something to do with the naming of the variables (or where you're defining them)

Comment: This should not be tagged with "java-me".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of `ItemEvent` comparison on the selected checkbox item.
For every click event, you should only check with one source item for the event.
In your case it would be either `cb1` or `cb2`.
But you are clicking on `Female` checkbox, but assigning its label to both `cb1` and `cb2`.
And hence both the checkboxes are seen with the same label.

Apply following changes and see how it affects.

```
  Checkbox cb = ( Checkbox ) e.getItemSelectable();

  if ( cb.getLabel().equals( "Male" ) ) {
    l1.setText( cb.getLabel() );
  }
  else if ( cb.getLabel().equals( "Female" ) ) {
    l2.setText( cb.getLabel() );
  }
```